# How to get the rasterbrick data which is greater than certain point in r?

Tags: r

I have rasterbrick or stack data with a total of 5355 nlayers. Now I only want the layers as stackbrick data that are higher than the 90th percentile of it. what I did try.

```
#data
Tmax_data #it is stack data
# 90th pecentile
Tmax_data_90 <- calc(Tmax_data, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE))
#selecting greater than 90th percentile 
greater_than_90 <- Tmax_data > Tmax_data_90
Tmax_data_subset <- Tmax_data[greater_than_90]
```